# remove element fetched from php clubed with dynamically created input from jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to dyanamically add inputs through click button. There is a remove input button along with the dynamically created input element. This will remove the input element. I have achieved this and further inserted the input values into mysql db. I have no problem with this.

Now when I'm fetching the existing values from my db (while loop), the existing input values are created along with the same remove button. Clicking the remove button do not remove the element, but when I click insert input and then remove, it works.

I'm not finding way to solve this. If anyone could please help. Below is my code.

MY HTML

```
<span id="insertblank">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="custom-button">Insert Input</button>
</span>

<div class="col-md-12 form-group fillin-answer">
  <!-- My PHP WHILE loop would actually be here, but for illustration, I have manually inserted the elements as below -->
   <!-- BEGIN INSERTED ELEMENTS -->
   <div class="blanksanswers" id="removeans1">
     <label class="removeans1">
        Input <span>1</span><span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove" data-id="1">
          Remove 1 Input
        </button>
     </label>
     <div class="input-group removeans1">
       <input class="form-control" id="fillin_answer1" name="fillin_answer[]" value="some values"/>
     </div>
   </div>
   <!--END INSERTED ELEMENTS-->
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
var count = 0;
var customButton = document.querySelector('#custom-button');
           customButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
               count++;
                   var new_input = '<div class="blanksanswers" id="removeans'+count+'"><label class="removeans'+count+'" style="color:#333D79FF; font-size:15px;">Input <span>'+count+'</span><span class="text-danger">*</span><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove" data-id="'+count+'">Remove '+count+' Input</button></label><div class="input-group removeans'+count+'"><input class="form-control" id="fillin_answer'+count+'" name="fillin_answer[]" /></div></div>';
                   $('.fillin-answer').append(new_input);
                   $('.removeans'+count).on("click",".remove", function(e){ 
                       e.preventDefault();
                       var id = this.getAttribute("data-id");
                       $("#removeans"+id).remove();
                       if($(".blanksanswers").length == 0) {
                           count=0;
                           questc=0;
                       }
                   })
               //}
           });
```

My codepen [Here](https://codepen.io/theveil/pen/ExPLRwV).

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove button is not working because you are adding `EventListener` on `custom-button` so it will only work once you have clicked on `custom-button`.

You can try the following code using `class` instead of `id` of the elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click','#custom-button',function(){
    var new_input = '<div class="blanksanswers" ><label class="removeans" style="color:#333D79FF; font-size:15px;">Input <span></span><span class="text-danger">*</span><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove">Remove Input</button></label><div class="input-group removeans"><input class="form-control" id="fillin_answer" name="fillin_answer[]" /></div></div>';
    $('.fillin-answer').append(new_input);
  });
  
  $('body').on('click','.remove',function(){
    $(this).closest('.blanksanswers').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="insertblank">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="custom-button">Insert Input</button>
</span>

<div class="col-md-12 form-group fillin-answer">
  <!-- My PHP WHILE loop would actually be here, but for illustration, I have manually inserted the elements as below -->
   <!-- BEGIN INSERTED ELEMENTS -->
   <div class="blanksanswers" id="removeans1">
     <label class="removeans1">
        Input <span>1</span><span class="text-danger">*</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove" data-id="1">
          Remove 1 Input
        </button>
     </label>
     <div class="input-group removeans1">
       <input class="form-control" id="fillin_answer1" name="fillin_answer[]" value="some values"/>
     </div>
   </div>
   <!--END INSERTED ELEMENTS-->
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help! :)